# Tkinter .after() not responding to keypress fast enough

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to animate a ball, that is be moving forward. In addition, if the user presses up or down button, it should move respectively.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class Movement:
    def __init__(self, _frame, _canvas):
        self.frame = _frame
        self.canvas = _canvas
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 150
        self.count = 0
        self.update()

        self.frame.bind_all("<Up>", lambda event: self.move_up())
        self.frame.bind_all("<Down>", lambda event: self.move_down())

        pass

    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= 10
        pass

    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 10
        pass



    def update(self):
        canvas.delete("obj")
        self.count += 10
        x2 = self.x + 50
        y2 = self.y + 50

        self.canvas.create_oval(self.x + self.count, self.y, x2 + self.count, y2, fill="red", tag="obj")

        root.after(1000, self.update)
        pass


root = tk.Tk()
width = 400
height = 400
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=width, height=height)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Movement(frame, canvas)
    canvas.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

There's an issue, though. Given the fact that the ball is moving every 1 second, it doesn't respond to the key press fast enough. As a result, if you click the up kick, the screen is updating after one second.

I know there's a .move() function inside Tkinter. However, due to many reason I cannot use that.

My main concern is the interval it take for the screen to be updated.

Comment: So pass a smaller number to `after`, then.

Comment: Then the ball will be moving faster, which is something I don't want.

Comment: if you are making a game Tkinter is awful - pygame is much better and is relatively easy

Comment: You could simply half the x, y increment and half the root.after so it updates twice as fast but updates half as much

Comment: @JoshuaNixon can you elaborate, please

Comment: Explain what your issue is in better detail

Comment: The problem is simple. The ball is moving to the left by 10 units every 1 second. While it's doing so, I want the user to have the ability to rise or lower it, by using the arrow keys up and down. As you know, tkinter runs on a single loop. As such, if I the user clicks the up button, tkinter will only show the result after one second, which is a bad idea. Something else I tried is update the screen every one millisecond, then increase the x value every second. Tkinter didn't like it.

Comment: @Cast Fellow: I just updated my code to be consistent with the bindings the way you were using them. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: So you want the result to be shown quicker? Not much you can do for tkinter to speed up the reaction time from press to input. Pygame is much much better option for this

Comment: "tkinter didn't like it" makes no sense. Tkinter doesn't particularly care. There's no technical reason why you can't update every millisecond, though that's using way more CPU than necessary. You only need to update around 30 fps or so.

Comment: @JoshuaNixon: your statement is not true. Tkinter can respond to a keypress or mouse click in under a millisecond. In this code, Tkinter is indeed responding to the keypress instantly, it's just that the OP's code won't take advantage of the new data until a full second has elapsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand you want to be able to keep the timer moving forward consistent but also be able to move up and down at any point even outside of the timer.

to accomplish this I moved the timer to its own function and allowed the up down functions to call the object destroy/create function.

I have updated you code to reflect that.

Take a look at this code and let me know if it helps.

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

class Movement:
    def __init__(self, _frame, _canvas):
        self.frame = _frame
        self.canvas = _canvas
        self.x = 10
        self.y = 150
        self.count = 0
        self.object_timer()

        self.frame.bind_all("<Up>",lambda event: self.move_up())
        self.frame.bind_all("<Down>",lambda event: self.move_down())

    def move_up(self):
        self.y -= 10
        self.update()

    def move_down(self):
        self.y += 10
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        canvas.delete("obj")
        x2 = self.x + 50
        y2 = self.y + 50
        self.canvas.create_oval(self.x + self.count, self.y, x2 + self.count, y2, fill="red", tag="obj")

    def object_timer(self):
        self.update()
        self.count += 10
        root.after(1000, self.object_timer)

root = tk.Tk()
width = 400
height = 400
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=width, height=height)
frame = tk.Frame(root, width=width, height=height)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Movement(frame, canvas)
    canvas.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If my answer helped you please consider accepting my answer by selecting the check box to the right of my answer :)

Comment: But this is moving it diagonally as well. What I was trying to achieve is when going up, the x axis should freeze.

Comment: @Cast Fellow: I just edited my answer to reflect what you want. This should stop moving the ball to the right until the timer loops.

Answer (score 0):

It's all just math. You can call update twice as much, and move the ball half as much if you want to keep the ball moving at the same speed while reacting to keypresses faster.

For example, instead of moving 10 pixels every second, have it move 1 pixel every tenth of a second. The end result is still 10 pixels every second. The animation will be smoother, and it will react to keypresses much faster.

---

By the way, there's no need to delete and recreate the oval every iteration. It's possible to move items on the canvas. Deleting and recreating will eventually cause performance problems do to how the canvas is implemented internally. Each  object you create gets a new unique id, and the canvas will slow down when it has a large number of ids. The canvas does not re-use an id.

I would also recommend against using `lambda`. Unless you need it, it adds complexity without adding any value. Just add an extra parameter to `move_up` and `move_down`:

```
self.frame.bind_all("<Up>",self.move_up)
self.frame.bind_all("<Down>", self.move_down)
...
def move_up(self, event=None):
    ...
def move_down(self, event=None):
    ...
```